# Can I have underfloor heating with solid oak floor?

Tags: heating, floor

I've seen that many underfloor heating mats (the electric ones) specify the need for tile or stone floor and I'm wondering if it will work as efficiently under a solid oak floor? (or any wood floor for that matter)

Also what will be the difference between 100, 150, and 200 w/m<sup>2</sup> in the heating mat? What is usually used in  alounge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a water based underfloor heating system fitted under wood (old pine I think, not oak) floorboards which works fine.

It will be less efficient than a tile or stone floor as wood has lower thermal conductivity than stone or tile. You would have to fit a more powerful heat source to gain the same temperature gain in your room. It might even be the case that you can't get mats that are powerful enough - the water pipes we have are too hot to touch with bare hands - if you had enough current to produce that amount of heat you might be in danger of melting the wires.

Comment: Good answer.  Adding to that: the less the flooring transmits heat, the more insulation you need below (else most of the heat "goes down" rather than up like you'd want).

Comment: Are you using metal spreaders to spread the heat between the joists, and did you insulate underneath the piping?

Comment: Yes we used metal spreaders and insulated underneath the piping

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The power per square meter has to be lower than for tile or stone, so you can either buy specialized lower-power products (Millicable/Milliclick is one such product), or just install heating cable less densely.

My guess is that you would use 100 W/m² for a timber floor (compared to 140 W/m² for a concrete floor), but follow the directions for the product you choose.